# Word for 'over-reacting in a moody way and leaving a room while everyone is watching'

Tags: single-word-requests

When I was a teen in High School, I distinctly remember coming across such a word while turning over the pages of a paperback dictionary.

The meaning was something like this:

A person who knows he has the attention of everyone in the room, overreacts and grumpily leaves the room (may be shutting the door behind). Imagining a teenage girl might help. What is the word for this?

P.S. Knowing the word would give me inner peace, as of now my ignorance of the word leaves me with a deep sense of dissatisfaction.

Comment: Was it *Storm out*??

Comment: No, it was a single word, pretty obscure one at that.

Comment: Was it lengthy?

Comment: I would say of moderate length, 5-8 letters. Can't remember though.

Comment: *Flouncing* out?

Comment: Nope, not the phrases. The word had the distinct components of "knowing everyone is watching", "overreacting" and "and leaving a room". The part about leaving the room was distinct to the meaning of the word.

Comment: Yes!!! This one's it. Flounce out. Thank you. But someone already answered. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Rio1210 - How is "flounce out" a single word when "storm out" is two?

Comment: @HotLicks As I was looking for a particular word that I knew before, so I was not receptive to the phrase *storm out*. The word **Flounce** alone has the meaning according to my paperback as - *"To move somewhere in a way that draws attention to yourself, for example because you are angry or upset."* 
Basically, the word flounce rang a bell in my head, the phrase *storm out*  is already familiar to me. Sorry if this caused any confusion.

Comment: But "flounce" would normally be uses to mean to act in a "showy" or "haughty" manner.  It doesn't convey a sense of being angry or grumpy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're right about the part about the room not being important to me. The example sentence in that dictionary was *She flounced out of the room* so I jumbled both the meaning and the sentence up in my memory (it's most likely 10+ years I last encountered the word).

Comment: @HotLicks None of the definitions of **Flounce** either in Merriam Webster, Oxford or Dictionary.com has anything remotely related to *"to act in a "showy" or "haughty" manner"*. Could you instead be thinking of the word ***flaunt***?

Comment: @HotLicks You are not correct when you say, "It doesn't convey a sense of being angry or grumpy". In fact, Oxford defines it as -- ***Go or move in an exaggeratedly impatient or angry manner***, using the exact word angry.
Google defines it as the following - 
**go or move in an exaggeratedly impatient or angry manner.**
and

**an exaggerated action, typically intended to express one's annoyance or impatience.**

Comment: Therefore this question is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I guess so.

Comment: @Rio1210 - As I would normally interpret it in the US it implies acting in a way to attract attention, indeed along the same lines as "flaunt".  It may be that that's an incorrect interpretation, but it's likely a common one, especially given that several other "fl-" words such as "flirt" convey a similar sense (and given that "flounce" is not a common word itself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One word for this is [flounce](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flounce) 
, given by the Oxford dictionary as:

> Go or move in an exaggeratedly impatient or angry manner.

as in

‘he stood up in a fury and flounced out’

Comment: That's two words, and less well recognized than "stormed out".

Comment: @HotLicks I agree with you that "stormed out" is more recognized. Nonetheless, I accepted this answer, as it was the word I was looking for.

Comment: @HotLicks: In my neck of the woods we're more likely to use ***stomped off*** than ***stormed out*** (unless we actually *want* the slightly "affected, florid, poetic" overtones of ***flouncing***).